# How to update the SESSION value on same page after AJAX call on post JSON value without refreshing page

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

## How to update the SESSION value on same page after AJAX call on post JSON value without refreshing page.

I'm stuck here. Any help solving the problem is highly appreciated. I what to run particular class in PHP based on the action button clicked. I.e When the user clicks the add button it initiates the AJAX call and sends the 'ADD' ID else if he/she clicks the update button it sends the 'UPDATE ID.  I want to perform this without updating the page. 
 
I have achieved getting the data, but the only issue is it **updates only when I refresh the page**

How do I update the SESSION in PHP once the AJAX sends the data. I'm a newbie, please take easy on me :) Thanks u

#### Index.php

```
<?php
session_start();
echo "SESSION: ".$_SESSION['pageType'];
?>

<!DOCTYPE>
<html lang="en-OM">

<div >AJAX: </div><div id="msg" style="display:inline"></div></div>
<a id="btnAdd" value="add" class="btnType" href="#" role="button">ADD</a><br>
<a id="btnUpdate" value="update" class="btnType" href="#" role="button">UPDATE</a><br>
<a id="btnDelete" value="delete" class="btnType" href="#" role="button">DELETE</a>

</html>
```

#### Jquery

```
   <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.btnType').click(function (ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            ev.stopImmediatePropagation();
            let pageID;
            pageID = $(this).attr('value');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'postData.php',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    pageType: pageID
                },
                beforeSend: function (data) {
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#msg').text(data);
                    console.log(data);
                    return data;
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log('<p>status code: ' + jqXHR.status +
                        '</p><p>errorThrown: ' + errorThrown +
                        '</p><p>jqXHR.responseText:</p><div>' + jqXHR.responseText +
                        '</div>');
                    console.log('jqXHR:');
                    console.log(jqXHR);
                    console.log('textStatus:');
                    console.log(textStatus);
                    console.log('errorThrown:');
                    console.log(errorThrown);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

#### postData.php

```
session_start();
if (!empty($_POST['pageType'])) {
    echo json_encode($_POST['pageType']);
    $_SESSION['pageType']=$_POST['pageType'];
    exit;
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you referring to here, what does update only after you refresh the page? _“How do I update the SESSION in PHP once the AJAX sends the data”_ - by assigning the new value to a session variable, exactly like you did with `$_SESSION['pageType']=$_POST['pageType']`. I think you are somehow confusing the actual state of your session data on the server, with what gets displayed on the client …?

Comment: Move `echo "SESSION: ".$_SESSION['pageType'];` inside your "msg" div. That way, when you run the AJAX call, it will get overwritten (because of `$('#msg').text(data);`). Also don't use json_encode if you're planning to only return one piece of text for display in the page - it's not necessary.

Comment: @ADyson I did what you asked, but still doesnt work. cos once you assign the value at server side it need to be refreshed inorder to update. Removing the json_encode gives me error.

Comment: "once you assign the value at server side it need to be refreshed inorder to update"...in that case probably your AJAX call is not working as it should. You need to do some debugging.

Comment: P.S. I should have said, that you should also remove `dataType: 'json'` from the AJAX when you remove `json_encode`. You are not using or needing any JSON for this functionality.

Comment: I added an answer with full code to make clear exactly what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work better:

Index.php

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE>
<html lang="en-OM">

<div >SESSION: </div><div id="msg" style="display:inline"><?php echo $_SESSION['pageType']; ?></div></div>
<a id="btnAdd" value="add" class="btnType" href="#" role="button">ADD</a><br>
<a id="btnUpdate" value="update" class="btnType" href="#" role="button">UPDATE</a><br>
<a id="btnDelete" value="delete" class="btnType" href="#" role="button">DELETE</a>

</html>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.btnType').click(function (ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        ev.stopImmediatePropagation();
        let pageID;
        pageID = $(this).attr('value');

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'postData.php',
            data: {
                pageType: pageID
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $('#msg').text(data);
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log('<p>status code: ' + jqXHR.status +
                    '</p><p>errorThrown: ' + errorThrown +
                    '</p><p>jqXHR.responseText:</p><div>' + jqXHR.responseText +
                    '</div>');
                console.log('jqXHR:');
                console.log(jqXHR);
                console.log('textStatus:');
                console.log(textStatus);
                console.log('errorThrown:');
                console.log(errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

postData.php

```
session_start();
if (!empty($_POST['pageType'])) {
    echo $_POST['pageType'];
    $_SESSION['pageType']=$_POST['pageType'];
}
else
{
  echo "error - no pagetype specified";
}
exit;
```

What I did:

1) move the initial echo of the Session value inside the "msg" div, so it can be overwritten by the result of the AJAX call

2) remove all references to JSON from the AJAX options and from the PHP. You aren't using (and don't need to use) JSON here to send a single piece of text.

3) added some basic fault tolerance to postData.php to ensure there is always some kind of output.

Comment: Thank you for sending me details code. I made the changes. Still the question remains. How can I add to the JSON value to PHP SESSION so that I can dynamically check the button action without refreshing the page?

Comment: There is no JSON value anywhere here! When you send a value via AJAX, it is not sent in JSON format unless you specifically tell JQuery to do that. But there is no need for it, so don't. Anyway, this code should ensure that your session is updated with a new value. It should also echo that new value so you can display it back on the screen. If that's not happening, then you need to do some detailed debugging, and explain to us precisely what **is** happening when you execute the code, so that we can help you fix it. Do you know how to use your browser's Developer Tools to debug JS and AJAX?

Comment: To explain you better what I mean, I'm adding code which should initiate each session when button clicked based on ID. Sorry if I'm to nerdy.
`<div >SESSION: </div><div id="msg" style="display:inline">
    <?php
   if(Session::get('pageType')=='add'){
       echo "ADD button Clicked";
    }elseif(Session::get('pageType')=='update'){
       echo "UPDATE button Clicked";
   }elseif(Session::get('pageType')=='delete'){
       echo "DELETE button Clicked";
    }
   ?></div>`

Comment: Right but that code executes **when you first load your page**. It is happening **before you have clicked the button**. Therefore it cannot work as you intend. When you click the button and run the AJAX, it makes a separate call to postData.php. That changes the Session. It then echoes the response. That response comes back to `data` inside the "success" function of the $.ajax. You then use JavaScript to put that value into the "msg" div in the page. That is how it must work. Why did you not just put the code as I have given you above? Try it like I have written, and then see.

Comment: Also what is `Session::get` anyway? I don't think that's standard PHP. Are you using a framework? In standard PHP if you want to get a session value you simply reference it like `$_SESSION["pageType"]`; as I have shown (and as per your own original code!).

Comment: P.S. I assume you have some more complicated reason for wanting to store this value in the Session in real usage? Because if all you really want to do is know which button was clicked, you can just use JavaScript directly for that, no need for AJAX, PHP or Sessions. What is your real intention for this feature?

Comment: Hmmm. Yes you are right. The code executes when I first load the page. I understand what you mean. How can I pass the Ajax value to the Method ? Which later I want to write code for each button based on what button was clicked passing the Ajax value? As per my understanding we cannot assign session variable here in my case. Session::get is just static function I using which uses $_SESSION...

Comment: _"How can I pass the Ajax value to the Method"_ ...to which method, exactly? The AJAX value is passed to postData.php. If you want to use some PHP code to change the output, then you must write it in postData.php. It can then echo the output back, and JavaScript can show it on the page.

Comment: e.g. you could change the "echo" line in postData.php to be `echo $_POST['pageType']." button clicked";` so that it outputs the value of the clicked button as well as some text (no need for the if statements, actually, since what you want to output is the same as the value itself).

Comment: But you know, if you just want to display which button was clicked, you can simply write `$('.btnType').click(function (ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        $("#msg").text($(this).attr('value') + " button clicked"); });` in the JavaScript. There is no need to save it in the Session, unless you need to keep the value for later in your application when the user moves to a different page. Like I said, you really ought to explain to me what you actually want to do when these buttons are clicked. It's not clear what, if any, of this code is actually necessary for your (real) requirements.

Comment: I'm attaching a image diagram of what I want to achieve.  The index page will have 3 buttons ADD, UPDATE and DELETE with assigned values and records below will update accordingly. All the 3 buttons will have its own method or function which will fire when clicked. This can be easily done with form submit form using GET or POST as the PHP can grab the POST data when the page refreshes each time and initiates the right function. I want to achieve this  **without refreshing the page** . I believe this can be only done using AJAX ?[My Plan](https://ibb.co/51Tyx5v)

Comment: Yes, that's right, if you don't want to refresh the page then you must use AJAX to communicate with the server and the database. So, if you just want to use it to add/update/delete data in the database, then you do need AJAX and PHP, but I can't think of any reason you need Session.

Comment: I used SESSION cos I didn't find any other idea to find solution for this. If not session, how can I pass the value of AJAX (ie; the button ID) into the PHP function without refreshing page?

Comment: By calling postData.php you are **already sending the value to PHP**. If you want to execute a PHP function, then execute it from within postData.php. I already told you that! Session is only useful for **next time you refresh the page, or go to another page**, because it can be used to store data in between page updates. But you are saying you don't want to refresh the page. Therefore, Session is not useful to you.

Comment: Got it! Thank you for making me understand :)